# Different result when running the same code through the Pycharm and Idle？

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

In recently coding I get a problem,it make me confused.

Here is the code:

Code1:

```
import tkinter
the_file_name=tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(the_file_name)
```

In Idle it running well and returns the correct result, but it make a mistake when running in Pycharm,the error message is:

```
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'filedialog'
```

The Code2 and Code3 can running well in both Idle and Pycharm.

Code2:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
the_file_name=filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(the_file_name)
```

Code3:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
the_file_name=askopenfilename()
print(the_file_name)
```

I prefer to use Code1 to complete my code, hope someone tell me why it did not work in Pycharm.

Comment: maybe they use different versions. Or you saved this in file `tkinter.py` and now `import tkinter` loads your file instead of Python module. And this is why you should add full error message (Traceback) in question because there is filename and we could see this.

Comment: BTW: `IDLE` is built on `tkinter` so it could do `import tkinter.filedialog` for own use and it has no problem with your code.